# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un target="_blank" , manteniendo la pestaña (página) inicial?

Tags: html

¿Es posible realizar un `target="_blank"` (Que se abra una nueva pestaña) pero que se mantenga en foco la pestaña principal? Al abrir la nueva pestaña se hace un poco por defecto a la nueva pestaña sin que yo quiera hacer eso

Comment: La nueva página, ¿es dentro de tu dominio o externa?

Answer (score 1):

No es posible con  `target="_blank"`  ya esto abre el documento en una nueva ventana o tab.

Una solución podría ser esta:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Hola <a href="http://es.stackoverflow.com" onclick="window.open('#','_blank');window.open(this.href,'_self');">
Abre en una nueva ventana es.stackoverflow.com </a> , pero continua en la misma!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Lo que hace en realidad es que abre la página actual en una nueva ventana, pero funciona ya que te mantienes en la misma página.

Comment: Aunque técnicamente funciona, esta solución no es ideal: 1) no irá bien si el usuario tiene las pop-ups bloqueadas; 2) si la URL tenía un valor en el #, éste se pierde (sería mejor hacer `window.open(window.location.href,'_blank')`); 3) si se ejecutaba algún JS al inicio o se descargaba algo, se vuelve a ejecutar

Comment: No, en realidad no me sirve porque lo aplico en un formulario

Comment: usar window.open(window.location.href,'_blank')); cierra la página y abre otra nueva!, Luis, creo que te falta detallar aún má tu pregunta! :)

Comment: Lo que pasa es que el blank lo uso en un formulario <form style="width:500px"  name="frmLogin" method="post" action="" id="frmLogin" target="_blank"> y necesito accionarlo. pero que se abra en una nueva pestaña el resultado pero manteniendo la pestaña inicial. Quiero que se mantengan las dos abiertas pero con el foco en la inicial

Comment: @LuisAlbertoAguileraClarke ¿el enlace es dentro de tu dominio o es a una página web externa?

Comment: Es una web externa. estoy usando un login de un sitio externo es porque necesito rescatar la sesión de esta. En estos momentos lo logro hacer, pero me pasa esto de la pantalla :(

Answer (score 0):

Como se describe en esta [preguna de StackOverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501095/window-opener-focus-doesnt-work), el control de las ventanas/pestañas depende del navegador y sistema operativo, y no se puede controlar de manera programática para evitar problemas de abuso de poder.

Existe la función [`window.focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/focus) para solicitar que la página/pestaña gane el foco de nuevo, pero es una solicitud y el navegador puede (y suele) ignorarla (imagina que una página pide obtener el foco cada vez que lo pierde, entonces el navegador nunca podría salir de ella). De hecho, este método no funciona en ningún navegador de los que he probado.

Una alternativa sería ejecutar alguna acción que fuerce el foco en el navegador, como por ejemplo un `alert()` o un `confirm()`. Así una "solución" al problema sería ejecutar un `alert()` con un mensaje cuando se pulse en el enlace... pero **este método sólo funciona en Chrome**; en Firefox e Internet Explorer, la nueva ventana/pestaña ganará el foco y la que la abrió se iluminará y/o parpadeará. El código sería simple:

```
<a href="http://es.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">Abre SOes en una nueva ventana</a>
<script>
var aux = document.querySelectorAll("[target='_blank']");
for (var x = 0; x < aux.length; x++) {
    aux[x].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        // hace falta el setTimeout o el alert se ejecutará antes de abrirse la ventana
        setTimeout("alert('Pulsaste en el botón!')", 10);
    });
}
</script>
```

Si lo que quieres es abrir una página externa para que el usuario inicie sesión (como parece indicar por los [comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10471/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-hacer-un-target-blank-manteniendo-la-pesta%C3%B1a-p%C3%A1gina-inicial#comment18297_10489)), otra alternativa sería abrir el enlace usando un `iframe` en la misma página en lugar de en una nueva ventana/pestaña. Para ello podrías usar un plugin ya existente (p.e. [fancyBox](http://jsfiddle.net/VNPzA/)) o crear algo propio; esto funcionaría en todos los navegadores aunque fallará si la página enlazada tiene la opción SAMEORIGIN activada.

Y finalmente otra alternativa que funciona en todos los navegadores pero que puede fallar por culpa del bloqueador de pop-ups: invierte el orden en el que quieres hacer las cosas, en lugar de abrir una ventana desde el formulario, abre el formulario en una ventana y usa la ventana original como destino de los enlaces.

Así, la primera página web estará vacía (o tendrá el contenido que quieras) y abrirá el formulario de esta manera:

```
<script>
window.open("pagina-con-el-formulario.html");
</script>
```

Y en la página del formulario, procesarías los clicks a enlaces externos y los abrirías en la ventana original usando `window.opener`. Sería algo como esto:

```
<a href="http://es.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">Abre SOes en una nueva ventana</a>
<script>
var aux = document.querySelectorAll("[target='_blank']");
for (var x = 0; x < aux.length; x++) {
    aux[x].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.opener.location.href = this.href;
    });
}
</script>
```

Este método funciona en todos los navegadores, pero tiene el problema de que como abres la ventana sin que haya una acción específica del usuario, el bloqueador de ventanas pop-up seguramente la bloquee (podrías hacer que en lugar de estar vacía tuviera un enlace al formulario).